# library in component only works when the component isnt created programmatically(Vuejs3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, node-modules

I have a Component called CodeSnippet.vue that uses that libary vue3-hightlightjs if i create the component like this

```
<CodeSnippet />
```

everything works but if I generate it with a method like this

```
renderCodeSnippet(){
        this.$refs.container.innerHTML = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < codeSnippetSysthem.codeSnippetarray.length; i++){
          let buttonView;
          let currentPosition = i;
          let _setTop = this.startX+(currentPosition % this.rowAmount)*300;
          let _setLeft = this.startY+Math.floor(currentPosition/this.rowAmount)*300; 
          buttonView = defineComponent({
            extends: CodeSnippet, data() {
                return {
                }
            }
          })
          const CodeSnippetElement = document.createElement('CodeSnippet');
          CodeSnippetElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.RenderCodeSnippet);
          this.$refs.container.appendChild(CodeSnippetElement);
          createApp(buttonView,{
            setTop: _setLeft.toString(),
            setLeft:_setTop.toString(),
            title: codeSnippetSysthem.codeSnippetarray[i].title,
            codeContent: codeSnippetSysthem.codeSnippetarray[i].codeContent,
            codeSnippetPosition: currentPosition,
          }).mount(CodeSnippetElement)
        }
      }
```

it doesnt work and gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')
    at withDirectives (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2774:1)
    at Proxy.render (CodeSnippet.vue?9038:6:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:902:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5615:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:187:1)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5729:1)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5743:1)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5525:1)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5483:1)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5085:1)
```

to simplify it the part i need and causes the crash in the component looks like this:

```
<template>
<pre v-highlightjs><code class="javascript">const s = new Date().toString()</code></pre>
</template>
```

I dont know if this is important but this is how I import the libary in my main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueHighlightJS from "vue3-highlightjs";
import "highlight.js/styles/solarized-light.css";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(VueHighlightJS);
app.mount("#app");
```

My goal is to have Syntax highlighting, I also tried different libaries but they didnt work for me.A solution where I have to use a different method to highlight code would be just as good as fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a bug from the library, just use another one